# Source for not singing Yamim Nora'im tunes during the year

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, high-holidays

I was told that one should not sing the tunes used for *davening* on the *Yamim Nora'im* during the year (the exception being during the month of *Elul*, in order to prepare for the High Holidays), because when one does sing them, the Books of Judgement are opened "upstairs".

Is there any source for this?

Comment: No idea. But they did sing Yamim Noraim melodies by the Lubavitcher Rebbe's farbrengens.

Comment: There's a Chabad tune only allowed (by Chabadnikim) to be sung on Yom Kippur and at weddings (something like that). Perhaps you're thinking of that.

Comment: I remember hearing this from Rav Hutner zt'l, but don't have a source as of now.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're thinking of [Arba Bavos](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.96.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.91.D7.94.D7.9D_.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.92.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.90.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.92.D7.95.D7.9F)? It's not (publicly) sung on Yom Kippur

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I've never heard it so don't know. I heard it gets sung three times: Yom Kippur, a Chuppah, and in the future to greet Mashiach.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14708&st=&pgnum=46&hilite=

Comment: Considering many Sephardim don't have "high holiday tunes" this question applies only to Ashkenazim, and so I'm doubtful that it would have a "reaction upstairs" that only happens because of a certain segment of klal Yisrael.

Comment: @DoubleAA בין הזמנים המתאימים לניגון ד' בבות: שלושה רגלים, פורים[5], י"ט כסלו, י"ב תמוז, חודש אלול, ימי הסליחות[6] וכן בשעת הובלת החתן לחופה ובסיבובי הכלה סביב החתן. אדמו"ר הרש"ב התבטא שי"ט כסלו הוא ראש השנה לניגון ארבע בבות. כמו כן מנגנים בשמחות ברית מילה, בר מצוה, ובסעודת החתונה. http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.96.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.91.D7.94.D7.9D_.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.92.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.90.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.92.D7.95.D7.9F

Comment: @ShmuelBrin i guess that was probably it. maybe my friend who told me had a specific version of that tradition

Comment: The Mishna Berura in 565:12 mentions not singing האדרת והאמונה in a Tzibur during the year - אין לומר האדרת והאמונה בצבור כ"א ביוה"כ הא יחיד יכול לומר האדרת כל השנה. - http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.565.12/he/On_Your_Way?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked in [this Otzar Hachochma forum](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=9994), so I draw on their knowledge.  Here are some highlights:

Hogeh Umeayein (and Gershon Gold in the comments above) noted [Shu"t Az Nidberu 14:21](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=9994), where he is asked this same question, and answers that he doesn't know of a source, but that it makes sense that such a thing would be true.

Yisrael Har Kesef notes that there are many other practices which may bring the Midas Hadin down, yet, he quotes a personal conversation with Rav Shlomo Fisher that "רק מי שיש לו שייכות לנסתרות צריך להיזהר מדברים אלו".

Ish Sefer quotes Rav Yuda Schenfeld saying that it has been told over in the name of the Chida, however, he couldn't find a written source for it.

Hatzev"i quotes Harav Shneur, who says there is no source for this.

Oreach Neta brings from Minhag Yisrael Torah that one should not sing such tunes from Chanukah until Tamuz (which would exclude more than just Elul):

> בספר מנהג ישראל תורה [סי' תריט אות ז] הביא מספר מנהגי מהריי"ו [סוליצא] אות תשנא הכותב שאין לנגן את ניגוני הימים נוראים מחנוכה שהוא גמר הדין ועד תמוז שזמני התשובה מבצבצים

Hi Sichasi quoted the question as posed to Rav Chaim Kanievsky, as well as his answer that it can be found in books of Chassidim:

> הגר"ח קנייבסקי שליט"א
>
> שאלה: האם יש טעם ומקור למנהג להחמיר שלא לנגן את מנגינות הימים הנוראים בשאר ימות השנה כי זה גורם למדת 
>   הדין
>
> תשובה: בספרי חסידים

Comment: And where is ספרי חסידים?

Comment: nowhere that I know of.  To me the two sources are "no source" or the 
 Minhag Yisrael Torah